# What does mov eax, dword ptr [eax] do?

Tags: assembly, x86

I understand that dword ptr is a size directive that indicates the size of what is being moved where and  I know that mov eax, eax is a form of nop code but what does this do?

I *think* it swaps the address of eax with the hex value inside but I am not too sure or even know why this would happen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The instruction `mov eax, eax` may be a no-operation code but that is *not* what you have here. You're loading from *memory*, as indicated by the `[]` "contents-of" characters.

It loads `eax` with the *contents* of memory (a 32-bit `dword` in this case) that is currently pointed to by `eax`.

Perhaps a graphical picture would help:

```
Before:
    eax:                 0x12345678
    memory @ 0x12345678: 0xffffffff

After:
    eax:                 0xffffffff
    memory @ 0x12345678: 0xffffffff
```

---

As to possible uses, there are no doubt many. One that pops into mind immediately is a linked list structure where you have something like this for a single element in the list (pseudo-assembly):

```
next:      word     ?         ; one word.
payload:   byte     ?(32)     ; 32 bytes.
```

If `eax` is used as a pointer to one of those elements, getting the *next* element would be done with the instruction you see:

```
mov eax, dword ptr [eax]
```

Comment: oh I actually didn't know [] meant contents of. Is it possible to do `dword ptr eax` without the brackets then?

Comment: @user2893243, that wouldn't make sense. `eax` is a _definite_ 32-bit value, whereas you may want to load from memory a single byte, a word, a dword or (in x64 at least) a quadword (for `rax` rather than `eax`).

Comment: ah ok so if I wanted to do `word ptr eax` which doesn't make sense in the first place I would simply do: `ax`. btw do you know any good books for assembly?

Comment: By the way, this method of loading a from a pointer register unto itself is often found in linked data structures (linked lists for e.g), since it allows the compiler to have a single register used as a "current element" pointer.

Comment: @Leeor: good use case, I've added that to the answer, albeit a bit late :-)

Answer (score 24):

It loads EAX with the DWORD value that EAX was originally pointing to.

In C terms its dereferencing the value that was originally held in EAX as follows: "eax = *eax"

Comment: +1 for _"dereferencing"_ pointer, it is in my opinion the simplest correct answer

Answer (score 5):

`dword ptr [eax]` - points to memory, which address is eax, so this statement copies 32 bit value from memory to `eax`

Answer (score 1):

About the *why* this would happen, it depends on the context.

For example, this could be used to load the value of `[eax]` on the stack, to use it as an argument for a function call. This operation cannot be done at once (as in `mov dword [esp + 4], dword [eax]`, cannot have two memory references in the same instruction), so it is split in two instructions:

```
mov eax, dword [eax]
mov dword [esp + 4], eax
```

Comment: For that, you'd typically do `push dword ptr [eax]`, depending on your strategy for handling stack args.  A more likely reason to find this in code is a loop over a linked-list or tree.  But yeah if it's not in a loop, it really could be any dereference when you don't still need the pointer value for later.  Like just working through some chain of one or two indirections to get to something.